# Google Workflow insert a bigquery job that queries a federated Google Drive table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-workflows

I am working on an ELT using workflows. So far very good. However, one of my tables is based on a Google sheet and that job fails on `"Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials."`

I know I need to add the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope to the request and the service account that is used by the workflow needs access to the sheet. The access is correct and if I do an authenticated insert using curl it works fine.

My logic is that I should add the drive scope. However I do not know where/how to add it. Am I missing something?

The step in the Workflow:

````
        call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.insert
        args:
          projectId: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
          body:
            configuration:
              query:
                query: select * from `*****.domains_sheet_view`
                destinationTable:
                  projectId: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
                  datasetId: ***
                  tableId: domains
                create_disposition: CREATE_IF_NEEDED
                write_disposition: WRITE_TRUNCATE
                allowLargeResults: true
                useLegacySql: false```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK for connectors, you cannot customize the `scope` parameter but you can customize if you put together the `HTTP` call yourself.

1. add the service account as a viewer on the Google Docs
2. then run the workflow

here is my program

```
#workflow entrypoint
main:
  steps:
    - initialize:
        assign:
          - project: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
    - makeBQJob:
        call: BQJobsInsertJobWithSheets
        args:
          project: ${project}
          configuration:
              query:
                query: SELECT * FROM `ndc.autoritati_publice` LIMIT 10
                destinationTable:
                  projectId: ${project}
                  datasetId: ndc
                  tableId: autoritati_destination
                create_disposition: CREATE_IF_NEEDED
                write_disposition: WRITE_TRUNCATE
                allowLargeResults: true
                useLegacySql: false
        result: res
    - final:
        return: ${res}
#subworkflow definitions
BQJobsInsertJobWithSheets:
  params: [project, configuration]
  steps:
    - runJob:
        try:
          call: http.post
          args:
            url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/"+project+"/jobs"}
            headers:
              Content-type: "application/json"
            auth:
              type: OAuth2
              scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
            body:
              configuration: ${configuration}
          result: queryResult
        except:
          as: e
          steps:
            - UnhandledException:
                raise: ${e}
        next: queryCompleted
    - pageNotFound:
        return: "Page not found."
    - authError:
        return: "Authentication error."
    - queryCompleted:
        return: ${queryResult.body}
```

Comment: Thanks Marton, the solution works. One note, the connector will wait for the query to finish, in this solution we need to poll to check if the job is finished. It is a sheet, so the time is pretty predictable, and a simple sleep will work, until the scopes are added to the connector.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1, http.post + googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.query

```
    call: http.post
    args:
        url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/"+project+"/queries"}
        headers:
            Content-type: "application/json"
        auth:
            type: OAuth2
            scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
        body:
            query: select * from sheets.sheets_data
            timeoutMs: 200000
            useLegacySql: false
    result: response
```

Option 2, Scheduled query + googleapis.bigquerydatatransfer.v1

```
    call: googleapis.bigquerydatatransfer.v1.projects.locations.transferConfigs.startManualRuns
    args:
      parent: ${scheduled_query_name}
      body:
        requestedRunTime: ${time.format(sys.now())}
    result: response
```