# Query BigQuery Spreadsheet external table and copy to Cloud Storage with Workflows

Tags: authentication, google-bigquery, google-drive-api, google-workflows

I'm working on a workflow to query a BigQuery table and export the result directly in Google Cloud Storage bucket. I have authentication access issue because the table I want to query is an external table from Google Sheet.

There is already a question about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956916/google-workflow-insert-a-bigquery-job-that-queries-a-federated-google-drive-tabl) but I'm not able to adapt it to my code.

Here is my code so far:

```
- init:
    assign:
    - project_id: "my_project_id"
    - bq_dataset_export: "my_dataset"
    - bq_table_export: "my_table"

    - bq_query: >
            select
                Col1
            from
                `my_table`
    - gcs_bucket: "bucket"
    - gcs_filepath: "bucket/file.json"

- bigquery-table-to-gcs:
    call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.insert
    args:
        projectId: ${project_id}
        body:
            configuration:
                extract:
                    compression: NONE
                    destinationFormat: "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
                    destinationUris: ['${"gs://" + gcs_bucket + "/" + gcs_filepath}']
                    sourceTable:
                        projectId: ${project_id}
                        datasetId: ${bq_dataset_export}
                        tableId: ${bq_table_export}
```

I know I need to add these lines of codes (or something very close) but I don't know where:

```
call: http.post
          args:
            url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/"+project+"/jobs"}
            headers:
              Content-type: "application/json"
            auth:
              type: OAuth2
              scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
```

The code below returns me a 404 error:

```
- init:
    assign:
    - project_id: "my_project_id"
    - bq_dataset_export: "my_dataset"
    - bq_table_export: "my_table"

    - bq_query: >
            select
                Col1
            from
                `my_table`
    - gcs_bucket: "bucket"
    - gcs_filepath: "bucket/file.json"

- bigquery-table-to-gcs:
    call: http.post
    args:
        url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/"+project_id+"/bq_query"}
        headers:
              Content-type: "application/json"
        auth:
            type: OAuth2
            scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
        body:
            configuration:
                extract:
                    compression: NONE
                    destinationFormat: "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
                    destinationUris: ['${"gs://" + gcs_bucket + "/" + gcs_filepath}']
                    sourceTable:
                        projectId: ${project_id}
                        datasetId: ${bq_dataset_export}
                        tableId: ${bq_table_export}
```

Edit #1

I have this workflow which is working but probably not the most efficient:

```
main:
    steps:
        - init:
            assign:
            - project_id: "project"
            - bq_dataset_source: "dataset_source
            - bq_table_source: "table_source"
            - bq_dataset_export: "table_source"
            - bq_table_export: "table_export"

            - bq_query_source: >
                    select
                        *
                    from
                        `hardcoded_table_path`
            
            - bq_query_export: >
                    select
                        *
                    from
                        `hardcoded_table_path`

            - gcs_bucket: "bucket"
            - gcs_filepath: "file_name.json"

        - bigquery-create-export-table:
                        call: BQJobsInsertJobWithSheets
                        args:
                            projectId: ${project_id}
                            configuration:
                                query:
                                    query: ${bq_query_source}
                                    destinationTable:
                                        projectId: ${project_id}
                                        datasetId: ${bq_dataset_export}
                                        tableId: ${bq_table_export}
                                    create_disposition: "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"
                                    write_disposition: "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
                                    allowLargeResults: true
                                    useLegacySql: false
        
        - bigquery-read-export-table:
            call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.insert
            args:
                projectId: ${project_id}
                body:
                    configuration:
                        query:
                            query: ${bq_query_export}
                            destinationTable:
                                projectId: ${project_id}
                                datasetId: ${bq_dataset_export}
                                tableId: ${bq_table_export}
                            create_disposition: "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"
                            write_disposition: "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
                            allowLargeResults: true
                            useLegacySql: false

        - bigquery-table-to-gcs:
            call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.insert
            args:
                projectId: ${project_id}
                body:
                    configuration:
                        extract:
                            compression: NONE
                            destinationFormat: "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
                            destinationUris: ['${"gs://" + gcs_bucket + "/" + gcs_filepath}']
                            sourceTable:
                                projectId: ${project_id}
                                datasetId: ${bq_dataset_export}
                                tableId: ${bq_table_export}


#subworkflow definitions
BQJobsInsertJobWithSheets:
  params: [projectId, configuration]
  steps:
    - runJob:
        try:
          call: http.post
          args:
            url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/"+projectId+"/jobs"}
            headers:
              Content-type: "application/json"
            auth:
              type: OAuth2
              scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
            body:
              configuration: ${configuration}
          result: queryResult
        except:
          as: e
          steps:
            - UnhandledException:
                raise: ${e}
        next: queryCompleted
    - pageNotFound:
        return: "Page not found."
    - authError:
        return: "Authentication error."
    - queryCompleted:
        return: ${queryResult.body}
```

Comment: if you do a select * from the external table and save it as a native table (use Save As), does it work w the native table?  the cheap workaround is a scheduled SQL query that is updating the native table w data from the external table

Comment: technically, you are supposed to be able to give the BigQuery service account access to the Sheet, and that should work.  but it is unstable in my experience.

Comment: Using GCP & non-GCP Google APIs is challenging because the auth models differ, so I try to cover it occasionally, e.g. http://gdg.community.dev/e/mns72c As @smoore4 suggested, giving the service acct Sheets access should work. As an alternative to Workflows, consider Apps Script (JS). I made an example of BQ+Sheets+Slides a few years ago which may be useful: http://developers.googleblog.com/2018/09/code-that-final-mile-from-big-data.html I cover the auth model diffs a bit in this Drive+GCS+Vision+Sheets Py sample: http://developers.googleblog.com/2020/10/image-archive-analysis-and-report.html

Answer (score 0):

Option 1, http.post + googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.query

```
    call: http.post
    args:
        url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/"+project+"/queries"}
        headers:
            Content-type: "application/json"
        auth:
            type: OAuth2
            scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
        body:
            query: select * from sheets.sheets_data
            timeoutMs: 200000
            useLegacySql: false
    result: response
```

Option 2, Scheduled query + googleapis.bigquerydatatransfer.v1

```
    call: googleapis.bigquerydatatransfer.v1.projects.locations.transferConfigs.startManualRuns
    args:
      parent: ${scheduled_query_name}
      body:
        requestedRunTime: ${time.format(sys.now())}
    result: response
```